# storing array checkbox value

Tags: php

I have a table with no.of users

```
$listuser = mysql_query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname,approve FROM user');
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<table>
          <tr><td>Name</td>
              <td>AdminApprove</td>
          </tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($listuser))
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
  $lastname  = $row['lastname'];
  echo '<tr>
           <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value ='.$id.'></td>
           <td>'.$firstname.''.$lastname.'</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="approve[]"></td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>';
echo '</table></form>';
```

After submitting the form

```
   $postedid = $_POST['id'];
   $approve = isset($_POST['approve']) ? 1 : 0;   
   $approvestudent = 'UPDATE user SET approve = '.$approve.' WHERE id = '.$postedid.'';
   $result_update = mysql_query($approvestudent);
```

I want to approve either one or more at a time for each student and the approved checkbox value need to store to the database either with 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['id']` is array not a string or integer

You can use php `serialize()` function to convert array into string

```
 $postedid = $_POST['id'];
   $approve  = $_POST['approve'];
```

should be

```
 $postedid = serialize($_POST['id']);
   $approve  = serialize($_POST['approve']);
```

Comment: Ya that was good, but when I approve only 2 users, its like approving all the users and storing with a value 1, but I need only that 2 users to be approved.

Comment: I am displaying all the users with check box in the above code